# Registering new devices to Azure IOT hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Just simple question:
I have created a new Service bus, Event hub and some shared access tokens with all rights, but registering a new device with iothub-explorer fails to 'unauthorized' message in Azure.

```
[tuomas@raspberry ~]$ iothub-explorer  login "HostName=mynew-iot.servicebus.windows.net;SharedAccessKeyName=mynewdevice-1;SharedAccessKey=NptRRzI9mhiXO2QKuhZq47iY24A7cbtxRpUDSQO5aSI=" --connection-string

Session started, expires Tue Apr 12 2016 20:02:13 GMT+0300 (EEST)
[tuomas@raspberry ~]$ iothub-explorer "HostName=mynew-iot.servicebus.windows.net;SharedAccessKeyName=device-1;SharedAccessKey=NptRRzI9mhiXO2QKuhZq47iY24A7cbtxRpUDSQO5aSI=" create dummydev

Error Unauthorized
```

Any toughts?

With Thanks,

~T

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's on purpose or not but the connection string in the second command doesn't match the one in the first one: the `SharedAccessKeyName` is different. Maybe it's just that.

If it's not just that, due to the way it's named I'm under the impression that you are using a device connection string when you should be using the service connection string (with a policy name in the `SharedAccessKeyName` field, such as the `iothubowner`). Whatever the policy is it should have the permissions to read and write to the registry. Unless you named such a policy "mynewdevice-1" ? One simple way to debug this is to use the `iothubowner` policy and associated key since it has full permissions.

Last thing, if you're using the "login" command, you don't need to specify the connectionstring again in subsequent commands (except to receive messages sent by devices, since this is done on the event hubs endpoint).

Comment: Sorry, messed those shared access key names. Device in hub is _device-1_. Can you clarify where I can get the service connection string?

Comment: hmm. I'm using classic (manage.windowsazure.com) portal, if I go to new (portal.azure.com) I can not see my event hub and service bus....

Comment: you don't need your event hub connection string for this operation, only the IoT Hub connection string, that you can find from the new portal (portal.azure.com), from your IoT Hub page, in Settings -> Shared Access Policies -> iothubowner (or any other policy, that fits the mission, iothubowner happens to have all the permissions).

Comment: What is the difference between device connection string and service connection string?

Comment: A "service" connection strings uses one of the shared access policies and key (see the "policies" section of your IoT Hub in the portal) and can have various access levels (edit the registry, send or receive messages to devices etc) whereas a "device" connection string is specific to a device id and can only be used to send and receive messages between an IoT Hub and a device.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have really messed these old and new portals.

After creating a new Service bus and event hub in new portal I can register my devices. The rest .... new question perhaps...

With thanks.

Comment: Is this a solution?